# Django limit the choice of a filed from one of the two Foreignkeys in a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Just curious about what would be the django way of achieving the following :

Model example :

```
class Match(models.Model):
    p1 = models.ForeignKey(Player , related_name='player1')
    p2 = models.ForeignKey(Player  ,related_name='player2')

    game1_winner = models. #Something that would limit the choice of the winner to only the two participants . 
    game2_winner = # the same .
```

Should i take care of this logic in the form or should i take care of it in the save method ? and what would be the most optimal way of achieving this ?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Great question. There is "limit_choices_to" but afaik it only supports "static" (no way to refer to the current model instance that i know of) values: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to This feature has been such since many versions of Django and certainly has room for improvement.

Comment: Looks like it also takes Q objects i will look in to it , thx for the reference .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would separate them out and handle the limitation in the view.

Something like this:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    p1 = models.ForeignKey(Player , related_name='player1')
    p2 = models.ForeignKey(Player  ,related_name='player2')

class Game(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

Then handle which Players are available to be designated Winner, based on the match. That's just my take on it.

Comment: I thought of that but i already have a lot of foreign keys , i was thinking there might be a django way to make it a bit easier .This also means i have to change the form since the are tightly bind together . :(

Comment: This is still the best way to handle this type of situation. Having a lot of foreign keys is not a problem if you optimize access using things like `select_related`. It's actually far more problematic to have repeating fields in your models. What if you want to eventually add a third game? Set up like this answer, you're already done. Doing it your way, you have to modify the model and probably other code as well.